# java: check compatibily between jar versions

Tags: java, jar, compatibility

Assume we have a set of projects "p1.jar", "p2.jar", etc, all them using library "foo-1.0.0.jar".

Assume a new version "foo-1.0.1.jar" is created. As an additional check, all projects p1, p2, ... are recompiled using new foo-1.0.1.jar. No compilation errors appears.

Now, in the production environment, foo-1.0.0.jar is replaced by foo-1.0.1.jar. No update of p1.jar, p2.jar, ... is done. Unfortunately, everything crashes.

It is possible to do some other checks to be 100% sure new library can replace old one?

Obviously, we are not talking about check of code errors introduced in new library or changes in the functionality (by example, if in new version function "sum" does a subtraction instead of an addition). But at least check changes in arguments, results, available classes, etc.

One example is, foo-1.0.0.jar contains method:

```
int m1() {
  // some code
  return 0; // always return 0, and ignored by the users
}
```

that in foo-1.0.1 it is changed to:

```
void m1() {
  // some code
}
```

Unfortunately, the result of the method is part of the name mangling in Java (not in C) and p1.jar will fail with "NoSuchMethod" exception when looking for "int m1()".

Comment: After reading your post again. If you only want to check the signature of the methods, a simple compile of your code against the new library would tell you if there is any incompatible change (for compile time). But what do you want to achieve with such a weak check? If it compiles without an error you have no guaranty that it will not fail at runtime.

Comment: @SubOptimal: exactly, guaranty of runtime compatibility is the target.

Comment: If you want runtime compatibility see my posted answer. The most secure way is run your test code with the new version.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp) to compare the new and old library archive for API changes.

But there is still the risk that a dependency of the library you check would not be detected.

Find below an example to demonstrate changes which might be undetected.

**ApiClass1.java**

```
class ApiClass {
    public static final int FOO = 23;
    public static void version() {
        System.out.println("version 1 FOO: " + FOO);
    }
}
```

**ApiClass2.java**

```
class ApiClass {
    public static final int FOO = 42;
    public static void version() {
        System.out.println("version 2 FOO: " + FOO);
    }
}
```

**ApiDemo.java**

```
class ApiDemo {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        ApiClass.version();
        System.out.println("ApiClass.FOO: " + ApiClass.FOO);
    }
}
```

- compile and build library for API version 1

  ```
  javac ApiClass1.java
  jar cf api_v1.jar ApiClass.class
  ```
- compile and build library for API version 2

  ```
  javac ApiClass2.java
  jar cf api_v2.jar ApiClass.class
  ```
- compile, build and run your code with API v1

  ```
  javac -cp api_v1.jar ApiDemo.java
  java -cp api_v1.jar:. ApiDemo
  ```

  output

  ```
  version 1 FOO: 23
  ApiClass.FOO: 23
  ```
- run your code with API v2, without recompilation

  ```
  java -cp api_v2.jar:. ApiDemo

  version 2 FOO: 42
  ApiClass.FOO: 23
  ```

The only reliable way is to compile your code against the new version, run all your unit-/integration test and check if they pass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the execution examples you show, it appears two lines of output, but in the code example I see a single "println" ¿?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Thanks for the information. It's fixed.

Comment: Sorry, now compiler complains "cannot find symbol method version()"

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I fixed my answer. Seems I missed something during copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unpack both jars, old and new, with `jar x`
2. Get class contents with `javap`
3. Compare contents from two jars

For example, if you have foo-1.0.0.jar and foo-1.0.1.jar in current directory, you may run this bash script:

```
# unpack old jar
mkdir foo-1.0.0
cd foo-1.0.0
jar xf ../foo-1.0.0.jar
# unpack new jar
mkdir ../foo-1.0.1
cd ../foo-1.0.1
jar xf ../foo-1.0.1.jar
# get unpacked classes contents
cd ..
for file in `find foo-1.0.0 foo-1.0.1 -name '*.class'`; do javap $file > $file.txt; done
# remove redundant .class files
find foo-1.0.0 foo-1.0.1 -name '*.class' | xargs rm
# compare jar contents
diff -r foo-1.0.0 foo-1.0.1
```

Sure, that's not fully automated method, you still should to check diff output manually. Still, that's better, than nothing.